# How to copy a file to share drive in aspx without using fileupload control

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net, file-upload

I need to copy the file from other drive to share drive in webpage. I cannot use FileUpload Control.  I use windowsIdentity to do the copy. It work on VS but when it post on the server. It shows the file cannot be found. Would someone tell me what should do. Thanks.

There is my code:

```
Dim ImpersonateContext As WindowsImpersonationContext = Nothing

Try
    ID = CType(User.Identity, WindowsIdentity)
    ImpersonateContext = ID.Impersonate()

    System.IO.File.Copy("C:\Users\tester\Desktop\test.pdf, "\\sharedrive\temp\test.pdf")

Catch ex As System.Exception
    Throw New System.Exception(System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name & vbCrLf & ex.Message.ToString)
Finally
    If Not ImpersonateContext Is Nothing Then                       
        ImpersonateContext.Undo()
    End If
End Try
```

Comment: Your exception handling can be improved: instead of grabbing the message, instead pass the caught exception to the constructor so that it becomes the InnerException.

Comment: presumably C:\Users\tester\Desktop\test.pdf is on _your_ local machine? Does this file exist on the server? If not then very obviously it isn't going to work...